# good product to physical lock down a mac mini server?

Tags: hardware, physical

Since the recent theft of a mac mini and macbook pro Im looking into products to lock down the mac mini server 2011 model. There are many cable solutions out there like kensington but the mac mini has no hole for that.

So my question is are there good products out there to lockdown a mac mini 2011 model?

I have found:

- http://www.sonnettech.com/product/maccuffmini.html
- http://www.tryten.com/products/Mac-Mini-Security-Mount.html

Does anyone have experience with these? Or advice in terms of locking down a mac mini?
With the above mount plates I think you have to screw them to your desk or with special superglue them to the bottom of your desk. Of course its not 100% proof but In the hope it will slowdown enough so they leave it as is ( too much hassle )

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your requirements. Do you want to discourage people from stealing the mac mini, do you want it to be impractical to steal it, do you want it to be impossible to steal it?

For instance, if it were enough for your scenario to scare off a thief by having to spend two minutes with a screwdriver in plain sight, a decently built basic mount to the desk is more than fine. But if your thief would not be scared to run in with a chainsaw cut the desk into bits and take the piece of desk that has your mac mini, you might need better means to secure it.

Some questions you can ask yourself to find if a mount will meet your requirements:

How scrutinized is the device when an attempted theft would take place?
Does the thief have a great incentive to steal it? (Such as launch-codes for a nuclear missile being on them or the device being a one of a kind gold plated version). What is the time-frame in which the thief would have to steal it?

If the thief does not have a bigger incentive than to sell it on eBay and would have to steal it in under 2 minutes and would be scrutinized when doing so, I think a desk mount will do.

Comment: Nice writeup ;) I plan to buy the mount for extra measure and have made a new strategy on backup and encrypting the mac mini itself thx